# mirroring a git repository is not working

Tags: git, mirror

I've read a handful of explainations on how to setup a mirror of an upstream and then periodically update the mirror to be up to date with the upstream.  It's not working.

Here is my example:

## Create the mirror from the upstream:

```
$ mkdir mirror ; cd mirror
$ git clone --mirror ssh://git@upstream.host.net:7999/myproject/myrepo.git
$ cd myrepo.git
$ git push --all ssh://git@mirror.host.net:7999/myproject/myrepo.git
$ cd .. ; rm -rf mirror
```

## Make a change occur, upstream:

```
$ mkdir upstream; cd upstream
$ git clone ssh://git@upstream.host.net:7999/myproject/myrepo.git
$ cd myrepo
$ git checkout -b newbranch
$ git push origin newbranch
$ cd ..; rm -rf upstream
```

## Update the mirror:

```
$ mkdir mirror; cd mirror
$ git clone ssh://git@mirror.host.net:7999/myproject/myrepo.git
$ cd myrepo
$ git remote update
Fetching origin
$ git branch -a | grep newbranch
```

```
<nothing>
```

Why doesn't my mirror get newbranch from the update?

Comment: Instead of `git remote update`, what if you say `git fetch`?

Comment: Makes no difference.

Comment: After reading the git documentation, it appears that "git remote update" isn't supposed to actually update the mirror (makes no attempt to push anything to the mirror).  It's just a fetch and nothing more.

Comment: What if you `git branch -a` without the grep?